Triggers for ADA-aliens dialogue?
In Satisfactory, when you collect Mercer Spheres and Somersloops, you frequently get dialogue exchange between ADA and the aliens. I wonder how it's decided when, and which dialogue you get. How is it?

Specific piece of dialogue assigned to specific collectible's location?
Only collectibles at specific locations trigger the dialogue, but which one to play is decided...

randomly?
sequentially?


It's all random?
The dialogue is sequential but whether I get it or not is random?
Some sort of mix of these?

It would likely take someone on 2nd playthrough of 1.0 to know the answer; to me it feels like the dialogue at least partially follows a sequence, early on ADA only detecting 'voice in our head', later actively engaging in discussion, but then the topics vary and don't seem to follow a sequence; it also feels like more "notable" locations with fancy structures for the collectibles trigger the dialogue while more generic ones often don't, but I'm completely unsure.

Quickly reading the wiki, Mercer Spheres have more constructed dialog and I think only trigger upon "X" amount collected (click the Expand button in the table next to the "Audio Files" header), while Somersloops I think are just quick, "one liners"  (warning spoilers)

Once you have collected enough Spheres there is a sequence of a little over two dozen audio clips (expand to see them) that play in order as you collect the spheres. After all of these interactions have been played, picking up further spheres generates dialog in a different manner. The other entity will sometimes say a short line when you approach Mercer Spheres and/or collect them, however these lines are quieter and do not show captioning like the dialog mentioned in the wiki. Many of these are the same as the dialog you get for picking up Somersloops such as "Witness a single strand of the tapestry".
I will mention, in my playthrough there was a bit of dialog (with captioning) on a sphere or sloop pickup(sometime after the ones listed in the wiki) where ADA says approximately that she doesn't need the pioneer to interact with the other entity and is muting it for "our benefit". I'm not positive if that was directly after clip 27 or if there were some "silent pickups" between.
At the time I write this I'm pretty sure the wiki listing of transcripts is incomplete.
